# PHPquery lib. and parsing XML

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, phpquery

I started using the phpquery thingy, but I got lost in all that documentation.
In case someone does not know what the hell I am talking about: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

My question is pretty much basic.
I succeeded at loading an XML document and now I want to parse all the  tags from it.

Using `pq()->find('title')` I can output all of the contents inside the title tags. Great!

But I want to throw every `<title>` tag in a variable. So, lets say that there are 10 `<title>` tags, I want every one of them in a separate variable, like: `$title1`, `$title2` ... `$title10`. How can this be done?

Hope you understand the question.
TIA!

Comment: I recently saw a lot of debate with a guy praising phpquery and its documentation but well here you go :)

Comment: I would not really call it documentation. It is a more of a bunch of topics in alphabetical order. With no logic what so ever.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
phpQuery::newDocument($content);
$allTitles = [];
pq('title')->each(function ($item) use (&$allTitles) {
       $allTitles[] = pq($item)->text();
});
var_dump($allTitles);
```

For example if there are 3 titles in the `$content` this `var_dump` will output:

```
array(3) {
       [0] =>
       string(6) "title1"
       [1] =>
       string(6) "title2"
       [2] =>
       string(6) "title3"
}
```